# Why I cannot access key value from webconifg in route file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my setting in webconfig file

```
<add key="pathName" value="test-server-url" />
```

and below is my routeConfig.cs

```
        string urlPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathName"].ToString();
        // routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:"TEST",
            url: urlPath +  "TEST/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TEST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I go to http://IP/test-server-url/TEST , i got 404 not found.
I did somehting wrong?

IF I remove all related to test-server-url , all is ok.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name:"TEST",
            url: "TEST/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TEST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: You missing the `/` - `url: urlPath +  "/TEST/{id}",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Stephen Muecke answered in his comment I'm just posting his answer to make it easier for others to know this question has been answered and to find the answer.

You are missing the `/` - `url: urlPath + "/TEST/{id}",`

So your code should be like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name:"TEST",
            url: urlPath +  "/TEST/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TEST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Hope this helps someone